# HTML5 API Drag error: originalEvent is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am going to use HTML5 API Drag Drop **[using this plugin](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/)**.

I also have added threedubmedia's jQuery plugin to have **[it's drag selection](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop/demo/selection)**
**http://threedubmedia.com/**

both of plugins work well on their own, but while I use them together HTML5 API doesn't work. when I start to drag jQuery logs this error: `event.originalEvent is null`.

I really don't know where the problem is to give more information.
Can someone help me with this `event.originalEvent` error. Thanks.